# Prevent USB device usage on linux

Tags: linux, usb, drivers

Is there a way in Linux to prevent usage of USB devices such as USB drives, Bluetooth Dongles etc.? I prefer something like black / white listing.

In some cases I have access to specific devices which should be allowed (like my personal USB Stick) and can get the device ID. All unknown devices shouldn't be able to be used. If possible, those devices shouldn't get any power at all.

On my research I have only found to disable the USB driver for a general approach to disable all USB devices.
Or to unmount a specific device ID during boot. However, if you plug the device in after boot process, or mount it again, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but it might still give you some help and advice.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65323/is-it-possible-to-usb-whitelist-in-linux

I case you want to know how I found it:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=linux+whitelist+usb+devices

Comment: Thank you that sure hits the right direction. I wonder: Isn't there any end point solution? Like in a company they have Ubuntu Desktops and want to prevent users from using USB devices?

Comment: Good question. I am sure something like this exists but it might be part of Red Hat Enterprise. But I get the idea. An equivalent of the Windows GPO but for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases I have access to specific devices which should be allowed (like my personal USB Stick) and can get the device ID.

Each USB device in Linux /sys has an `authorized` attribute – if it's set to 0, none of the USB interfaces in that device will have drivers attached to them, so the device will be nonfunctional.

Hubs (including the "root hub" inside your computer) additionally have an `authorized_default` attribute which sets the default authorization for devices connected to that hub. If it's set to 0, new devices will not be authorized until something manually writes '1' to their 'authorized' attributes.

These device attributes appear as files under /sys, but they're more commonly managed using udev rules – e.g. writing a rule that sets `ATTR{authorized}="0"`  will deauthorize the device. For example:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
TEST!="authorized", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
# Set default for hubs
TEST=="authorized_default", ATTR{authorized_default}="0", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
# Allow some devices
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Yubico", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Yubikey_NEO*", ATTR{authorized}="1"
LABEL="deauthorize_end"
```

The [USBGuard](https://usbguard.github.io/) daemon can automate this, as well as doing additional checks such as verifying which interfaces are provided by the device. (Just because a device's name is "USB Flash Drive", that doesn't stop it from being a keyboard.) For example:

```
allow 1050:0010 serial "0001234567" name "Yubico Yubikey II" with-interface "03:01:01"
```

Note that these solutions handle *only* traditional USB – they don't handle Thunderbolt devices, nor FireWire devices (if you still happen to have such ports). You can use the [bolt] daemon to secure Thunderbolt 3 ports.

> If possible, those devices shouldn't get any power at all.

The problem is that you cannot get the device ID of an unpowered device.

It is sometimes possible to turn off power to individual USB ports using `uhubctl` (depending on controller); however, if you power-off a port in reaction to an unauthorized device, the system will never know when an *authorized* device is connected to the same port.